# C# How to make Dataset 1 To show only Data for Customer

Tags: c#

I have this code i have been working on since yesterday which doesnt work as expected.

Now the thing is, I have 2 datasets to generate information from the database into a Reportview and then on one Dataset, i use 2 tables (Transaction and Account_info ) to generate Data. Both bring their information correctly, no problem for that but now here the problem comes.

if i put the identifier (Account Number) to search to generate account statement for say Mr A, it would show Details for A and Mr B, then if i put identifier for Mr B it would show account statement for Mr B and Mr A. I only want it to generate statements for one person. ie . if its account Number for Mr. A show only data for Mr A, and if its for Mr B, show only data for Mr B.

The Dataset for this is the DataSet1 and i want it to show information for just one customer

My code looks like this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;

namespace TmpZ
{
    public partial class BalanceSheet : Form
    {
        string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnData"].ConnectionString;
        public BalanceSheet()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BalanceSheet_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void reportViewer1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (accountNo1.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Account Number");
            }
            else
            {
                DataTable dtb = new DataTable();
                DataTable dtb2 = new DataTable();
                dtb2 = GetAddressInfo(dtb2);
                dtb = GenerateBankStatement(dtb);
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                ReportDataSource rpd = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dtb);
                ReportDataSource rpd2 = new ReportDataSource("DataSet2", dtb2);
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rpd);
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rpd2);
                reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
            }
        }

        private DataTable GetAddressInfo(DataTable dt)
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(constring))
            {
                try
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select fullname as [fullname], accountNo as [accountNo], ccy as [ccy] from account_info where accountNo = '" + accountNo1.Text + "'", cn);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }

        private DataTable GenerateBankStatement(DataTable dt)
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(constring))
            {
                try
                {
                    string dateF = Convert.ToDateTime(dateFrom.Text).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                    string dateT = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTo.Text).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT account_info.fullname as [fullname], account_info.accountNo as [accountNo], account_info.ccy as [ccy], account_info.address as [address] , transactions.id as [id], transactions.transaction_desc as [transaction_desc], transactions.credit as [credit], transactions.debit as [debit], transactions.balance as [balance], transactions.transaction_date as [transaction_date] FROM  transactions CROSS JOIN account_info WHERE(account_info.accountNo = '" + accountNo1.Text + "') AND(transactions.transaction_date BETWEEN '" + dateF + "' AND '" + dateT + "')", cn);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note on coding style: there’s no reason to give the datatable as an argument to a method, then return it and assign back to the variable. This is a complete no-op and will only confuse someone reading the code or using the methods.

Comment: Ok thank you. Now i managed to have it work, but it shows one data twice. on the statement area. (Dataset 1) Any ideas what could be the cause? @SamiKuhmonen

Answer (score 0):

Ok i fixed it. I had to fix some very buggy queries and it works as i expected now.  In case of someone who would be needing something like that in future.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;

namespace Tmpz
{
    public partial class BalanceSheet : Form
    {
        string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnData"].ConnectionString;
        public BalanceSheet()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BalanceSheet_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void reportViewer1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (accountNo1.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Account Number");
            }
            else
            {
                DataTable dtb = new DataTable();
                DataTable dtb2 = new DataTable();
                dtb2 = GetAddressInfo(dtb2);
                dtb = GenerateBankStatement(dtb);
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                ReportDataSource rpd = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dtb);
                ReportDataSource rpd2 = new ReportDataSource("DataSet2", dtb2);
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rpd);
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rpd2);
                reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
            }
        }

        private DataTable GetAddressInfo(DataTable dt)
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(constring))
            {
                try
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select fullname as [fullname], accountNo as [accountNo], ccy as [ccy] from account_info where accountNo = '" + accountNo1.Text + "'", cn);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }

        private DataTable GenerateBankStatement(DataTable dt)
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(constring))
            {
                try
                {
                    string dateF = Convert.ToDateTime(dateFrom.Text).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                    string dateT = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTo.Text).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                    // SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT account_info.fullname as [fullname], account_info.accountNo as [accountNo], account_info.ccy as [ccy], account_info.address as [address] , transactions.id as [id], transactions.transaction_desc as [transaction_desc], transactions.credit as [credit], transactions.debit as [debit], transactions.balance as [balance], transactions.transaction_date as [transaction_date] FROM  transactions CROSS JOIN account_info WHERE(transactions.accountNo1 = '" + accountNo1.Text + "') AND(transactions.transaction_date BETWEEN '" + dateF + "' AND '" + dateT + "')", cn);
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select id as [id], transaction_desc as [transaction_desc], credit as [credit], debit as [debit], balance as [balance], transaction_date as [transaction_date] from transactions where accountNo1 = '" + accountNo1.Text + "' and transaction_date between '"+ dateF + "' and '"+ dateT + "'", cn);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```